# jQuery Validate plugin and NiceSelect: validation errors

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I'm using the jQuery Validator and jQuery Nice-Select plugins but I'm having two problems when trying to validate the form. Take a look:

**This is the html:**

```html
<form id="ads-form" data-aos="zoom-out-down" method="post" data-aos-duration="300" data-aos-delay="150" data-aos-once="true" id="the-form" class="cads-form">
  <!-- Form Fileds -->
  <div id="ads-section" class="ads-container">
    <label class="control-label label-cads">* State:</label>
    <select class="dropdown-content ads-n wide" id="ads-state" name="ads-state">
      <option data-display="Select State" selected></option>
      <option value="ST1">State 1</option>
      <option value="ST2">State 2</option>
      <option value="ST3">State 3</option>
    </select>
    
    <label class="control-label label-cads">* City:</label>
    <select class="dropdown-content n-city wide" id="ads-city" name="ads-city">
      <option data-display="Select City" selected></option>
      <option value="CT1">City 1</option>
      <option value="CT2">City 2</option>
      <option value="CT3">City  3</option>
    </select>
    
    
    <div class="text-center ca-button-wrap">
      <br/><br/>
      <button class="btn btn-default cads-button" id="ads-button" type="submit">NEXT <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #0C2738;
}
form {
  margin: 2%;
}
.nice-select {
  margin: 1%;
}
button {
  margin: 1% 0 0 0;
}
.error {
  color: #DDAA40;
}
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  <!--Nice select Init -->
  $('#ads-state, #ads-city').niceSelect();
  <!--Validate Plugin-->
  $(function(){
        $("#ads-form").validate(
          {
            ignore: [],
            rules: 
            {
              'ads-state': 
              {
                required: true,
              },
              'ads-city': 
              {
                required: true,
              },
            },
            messages: 
            {
              'ads-state': 
              {
                required: "Select a State"
              },
              'ads-city': 
              {
                required: "Select a City"
              },
            }
        });
    });
  <!-- Remove error on Select change-->
   $('#ads-state').change(function () {
      $(this).valid();
   });
});
```

When I click the "Next" button if the selects are blank, the validation works perfectly. But when selecting a State, the error message is still displayed.
In addition, the select "City" does not display the error message when selecting an empty option. What could be happening?

[See an example here - Codepen link](https://codepen.io/boninho/pen/KKzKzeq)

Comment: Hi, not sure, is the form using standard input elements

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand.